# Sporting events held more than 4 years apart

Tags: international-sports

The Olympics are held every 4 years and all other major sporting events (soccer and rugby world cups etc.) are held on 4 year cycles to avoid clashing with the Olympics.

Are there any sporting events held regularly more than 4 years apart?

Comment: Also, this; http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9564/why-have-major-sporting-events-been-held-every-4-years

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least two Swiss Wrestling ([Schwingen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwingen)) competitions are held every 6 years.

The [Umspunnen-Schwinget](http://www.unspunnen-schwinget.ch/76/Ranglistenarchiv.html) in Interlaken is held every 6 years. The last events were in 1999, 2006 (the 2005 event was postponed due to rain) and 2011. The next event will be in 2017.

The [Kilchberger Schwinget](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilchberger_Schwinget) is also held every 6 years, with the last events in 2008 and [2014](http://www.srf.ch/sport/mehr-sport/schwingen/sempach-gewinnt-den-kilchberger-schwinget), and the next to be held in 2020.

It is interesting to note that the biggest event, the [Eidgenössisches Schwing- und Älplerfest](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eidgen%C3%B6ssisches_Schwing-_und_%C3%84lplerfest) is held every 3 years. Schwingen is not an Olympic sport, so there is no need to synchronize with the Olympics, but it may be an advantage for local festivals to avoid clashing with the national festival.

Answer (score 1):

Over the years the [Rugby League World Cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugby_League_World_Cup) has ranged from every 3 years up to every 8 years.  The most recent gaps being 8 years from 2000 to 2008 and then 5 years to 2013.  However, due to the switch in hemispheres, the next world cup will be a more traditional 4 year gap.